# Is this possible to install Magento 1.9.3 using the command line

Tags: magento-1.9, installation

I'm trying to create a Dockerfile for a little demo project and I was going to simply install the magento the way I want it with the commandline from Ununtu container.

I found some solutions ([like this](https://magento2.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/m1wiki/pages/14024855/Installing+Magento+via+SSH) ) which suggest getting it from here, but the links are obviously outdated:

```
wget http://www.magentocommerce.com/downloads/assets/1.9.2.3/magento-1.9.2.3.tar.gz
```

Is there a valid direct link to 1.9.3 archive nowadays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get it from a bunch of different places including this one

```
git clone git@github.com:OpenMage/magento-mirror.git
```

Comment: I was able to clone it over https with `git clone https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror.git` and it installed ok. There's a typo: `Git` must not be capitalized in your example. And thanks a lot for your answer!